# Group action of $\mathbb Z$ on infinite strip is homeomorphic to the Mobius Band

Tags: algebraic-topology, mobius-band

I am trying to prove that:

> Given $X=R×[-1, 1]$ and the action of $\mathbb Z$ as $m(x,y)=(x+m, (-1)^m y)$, prove that the space $X/Z$ is homeomorphic to the Moebius Band.

Since there is no homeomorphism between $X$ and $[0,1]^2$, where the MB is usually defined, I am trying to work directly on quotients.

My idea is to separate the action of even and odd integers, thus sending part of the orbit of a given $(x,y)$ to $(0,y)$ and the other to $(1, 1-y)$ but I cannot quite formalise it.

I am new both to group action and the forum, so excuse me if my reasoning may bene trivial.

Comment: And how exactly you define the Mobius band? You would normally define a map $X\to MB$ and then show that it is a quotient map and that the "kernel" (or more precisely relationship $x\sim y$ iff $f(x)=f(y))$ coincides with the action relationship.

Comment: I would define It as [0,1]² with (0,y)~(1,1-y)

Comment: Do you see why the MB is also $[0,1]\times [-1,1]$ with $(0,y) \sim (1, -y)$ ? Then do you see how to define a map $X\to MB$ and see what its "kernel" is, and then use a standard topology trick to go from "continuous bijection" to "homeomorphism" in such cases ?

Comment: I see the first and maybe the last ( proove it is open). But I can't define such a map, in general, I feel it rather diffucult to define map into quotients